# How is a property related to "self" and vice-versa?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

My question is two-part:

**First**, Say I have a class:

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject

-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

**MyClass.m**

```
@implementation MyClass

-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.name = name;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

My question: I know that self will hold the name property strongly. But how will the name property relate to self? What I mean is that I can access name as self.name but while class instantiation, how is the children of self (which in this case is name) related to self? I am imagining the structure of the class as a tree, with the parent holding strong reference to the children and the children holding a weak reference to the parent. I want to know if I am thinking about it correctly or not. My guess is it will be a weak relationship.

**Second**, if I add a method which has a block that references the name property. So my updated implementation of MyClass.m is:

**MyClass.m**

```
@implementation MyClass

-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.name = name;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)doSomeStuff
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        self.name = @"Name changed inside block";
}];
}

@end
```

My second question is: I am not referencing self directly inside my block. So, I guess there is no retain cycle here. But I am referencing name property which is held by self. So does this create a retain cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that `self` will hold the `name` property strongly. But how
>   will the `name` property relate to `self`?

Each property will have a *backing instance variable*, conventionally named the same as the property with a leading underscore and a getter and/or setter method.  There is no relationship; the property generally makes the class instance larger (due to additional instance variable) and the class larger (due to additional methods).

> I am not referencing self directly inside my block. So, I guess there
>   is no retain cycle here. But I am referencing name property which is
>   held by self. So does this create a retain cycle?

Yes you are referencing `self` directly, so a retain cycle is possible.  However a retain cycle can only happen under certain circumstances, and it's often just safer to avoid this by creating a weak reference to `self` and using that within the block.

Answer (score 2):

First: The name property holds no relationship to `MyClass`, weak or otherwise.  (That is, if you pass `name` to some arbitrary method, it doesn't carry any reference to the `MyClass` instance where it was a property.)

Second: Since you're simply executing the block rather than storing it, I don't see an opportunity for a retain cycle.

Answer (score 2):

1: The `MyClass` instance has retained the `name` property, `name` property itself has no idea what is `MyClass` and therefore , there is nothing referring from String-name to the `MyClass` itself.

2: In the following code

```
-(void)doSomeStuff
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        self.name = @"Name changed inside block";
}];
}
```

`self.name = @"Name changed inside block";` is the same as `[self setName:@"Name changed inside block"];`

So you are actually retaining `MyClass` instance inside Block and then executing its method to update the name , ( block needs pointer to this Name to change it , right ? block retains class object which contains this property ) , you are not retaining the property name itself.

Answer (score 1):

*But how will the name property relate to self? My guess is it will be a weak relationship.*

The `name` property does not have a reference back to `self`, so the attributes `strong` and `weak` don't apply.  An object instance is just a collection of instance variables, gathered into a struct.  When we talk about object memory management, we are talking about the memory containing that struct.  It doesn't make sense to say that a property (really the instance variable backing the property) has a reference to anything.  It is simply one part of what `self` is.

Answer (score 1):

> My question: I know that self will hold the name property strongly. But how will the name property relate to self? What I mean is that I can access name as self.name but while class instantiation, how is the children of self (which in this case is name) related to self? I am imagining the structure of the class as a tree, with the parent holding strong reference to the children and the children holding a weak reference to the parent. I want to know if I am thinking about it correctly or not. My guess is it will be a weak relationship.

The children *can* have a reference to the parent and then it should be weak for the reasons you mentioned. But `NSString` instances does not have such an up-reference. So there cannot be a retain cycle.

In general it is up to you to manage such inverse relationship. (Core Data does it automatically in its default setters,if you insert a inverse relationship.) Nothing is done automatically, no definition of an up-reference, no setting of a up-reference.

> My second question is: I am not referencing self directly inside my block. So, I guess there is no retain cycle here. But I am referencing name property which is held by self. So does this create a retain cycle?

You refer `self` inside the block, because you use it. Period.

But a retain cycle needs two references. As long as `self` is used inside the block, but the block is not stored in a property of `self` (directly or indirectly) no retain cycle can occur.

Comment: Say, if I were storing this block in a property of self. Then, do I need to create a weak ref to self and then update name property inside the block to avoid the retain cycle?

Comment: If you do that, you have a retain cycle. That does not mean that you have to weakify `self`, even this is *one* and the usual pattern to deal with it. Another one would be to manually break the retain cycle, when the operation is completed.